# CSS vertical-align bottom not work on iphone

Tags: css, html

My source code is as link: [Source Code](http://jsfiddle.net/hrhktkbzyy/0kwnL8k8/12/)  The demo shown on PC is exactly what I want, but the problem is that when I show the same code on iphone(and some android phones), is not correct.

HTML:

```
<div class="container divinline">
    <div class="row1 ">ROW ONEROW ONEROW ONEROW ONEROW ONEROW ONEROW ONEROW ONEROW ONEROW ONEROW ONEROW ONEROW ONEROW ONEROW ONEROW ONEROW ONEROW ONEROW ONEROW ONEROW ONEROW ONEROW ONEROW ONEROW ONEROW ONEROW ONEROW ONEROW ONEROW ONEROW ONEROW ONEROW ONEROW ONEROW ONE</div>
    <div class="row2">ROW TWO</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.divinline {
    display:inline-block;
}
.container {
     color:#FFF;
    height:60px;
    background:#ffee12;
    width:50%;
    text-align:left;
}
.row1 {
    background:#450011;
    font-size:12px;
    height:60%;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.row2 {
    background:#333333;
    font-size:12px;
    height:40%;

}
.row1:before, .row2:after {
    content:'';
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

As you see, what I want is ROW1's text aligned to the bottom, which is good as demo by the link.  But when I show it in iphone, the ROW1's text was aligned to the middle, which is not I want.

Comment: Try to add **!important**, vertical-align:bottom !important;. Hope it helps.

Comment: `vertical-align` should not affect block-level elements (like .row1), but it seems the current desktop Chrome has a bug here. Behaviour in iPhone is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be within your CSS.

You tell it to `vertical-align: middle;`

Try this:

```
.row1:before, .row2:after {
    content:'';
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```